# Using ConfigurationManager's OpenExeConfiguration and GetSection,(Custom config file and section)

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to retrieve a custom configuration section from a config file other than the app.config or web.config.

I tried using the System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager's OpenExeConfiguration and GetSection method calls together but without luck. My intention is to define custom configuration sections for interchangeable process adapters and contain the custom config section in a separate config file other than app.config and web.config. I see plenty of examples for appsettings and connectionstrings.

```
static private DigiKeyReadTaskConfigSection digiKeyReadTaskConfigSection;
  static DigiKeyReadTaskConfigSection DigiKeyReadTaskConfigSection {
     get {
        if (digiKeyReadTaskConfigSection == null) {
           digiKeyReadTaskConfigSection = (DigiKeyReadTaskConfigSection)ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("ReadTask.config").GetSection("DigiKeyReadTaskConfigSection");
        }
        return digiKeyReadTaskConfigSection;
     }
  }
```

The `digiKeyReadTaskConfigSection = (DigiKeyReadTaskConfigSection)ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration` call seems to be working however the `(DigiKeyReadTaskConfigSection)ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("ReadTask.config").GetSection("DigiKeyReadTaskConfigSection")` returns null.

The ReadTask.config file lives in the bin file of the App:

```
   <configuration>   <configSections>
        <section name="DigiKeyReadTaskConfigSection" type="DataReadInc.WebSiteRead.TaskConfigSection.DigiKeyReadTaskConfigSection, DataReadInc.WebSiteRead" />
        <section name="ArrowReadTaskConfigSection" type="DataReadInc.WebSiteRead.TaskConfigSection.ArrowReadTaskConfigSection, DataReadInc.WebSiteRead" />   </configSections>   <DigiKeyReadTaskConfigSection DigiKeySiteURL="http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?WT.z_header=search_go&amp;lang=en&amp;site=us&amp;keywords="
                                    SiteLogInURL="https://ordering.digikey.com/RegisteredUser/Login.aspx,formName=" SiteLoginId="X" SiteLoginPassword="X" />   <ArrowReadTaskConfigSection ArrowAmericaSiteURL="http://components.arrow.com/part/search/"
                                      SiteLoginURL="http://components.arrow.com/login/processlogin#" SiteLoginId="X" SiteLoginPassword="X" /> </configuration>
```

I have seen this type of setup with Spring.Net and a J2EE implementation so I am sure it is possible. I can just put my custom config sections in the App.config or web.config file, however it would be significantly cleaner for them to exist in their own config file.

Answer (score 2):

Use [ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134269.aspx). `OpenExeConfiguration` relates to a certain exe.

Comment: After some more searching I tried another approach:

       ExeConfigurationFileMap fileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
                   fileMap.ExeConfigFilename = "ReadTask.config";
                   Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(fileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
                   digiKeyReadTaskConfigSection = (DigiKeyReadTaskConfigSection)configuration.GetSection("DigiKeyReadTaskConfigSection");

It works!

Comment: @user1165254 - this is the correct answer.  Thanks.